# find number of updates done in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

What I am doing is editing the data of MySQL data using PHP using form.

I have two text field as name and mobile number. When I click on edit, I get same data in text field and below I have Save button. When I do changes I get response as done, but when I click edit and don't do any changes in text field and click Save I get response as fail.

Below is code for SAVE button.

```
$sql = mysql_query("
    UPDATE userInfo SET fullName='$fullName', 
    mobileNumber='$mobileNumber' 
    WHERE id=$tagNumberId"
);

if (mysql_affected_rows()==1) {
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

I am worried about `mysql_affected_rows()`.

Above makes me think that if data is same in UPDATE statement, `mysql_affected_rows()` will return 0 and if data is not same in UPDATE statement, `mysql_affected_rows()` will return 1.

Is this right? If it is right, how to deal with whether the update is done or not?

Comment: Well, **what are you trying to detect?** What is the "fail" branch supposed to mean? Also: the `mysql` extension is deprecated (you should switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` ASAP) and the code might be vulnerable to SQL inject (you should prefer prepared statements instead of injecting variables).

Comment: @Jon : if I don't change any values in textfield and click save, output of `mysql_affected_rows()` comes as 0 (and I was expecting as 0)

Comment: Please use PDO and read about SQL Injection!!! In terms of update and your "fail", MySQL is smart enough to detect that your query will not change anything in DB so affected rows = 0

Comment: @All : I am using PDO but for simplification here, I'm using normal update statement..

Comment: @FahimParkar: OK, it comes as 0. That still doesn't answer my question: what is the "fail" branch supposed to mean?

Comment: @Jon : When fail will come, I want to tell user that user is not edited. Please try again. FAIL means, user is not edited.

Comment: @FahimParkar: There are three reasons why no records might be updated: a) the fields were unchanged, b) the `id` does not exist, c) some problem with the server or connection. "Please try again" will only work for (c), which you can detect reliably with `if($sql === false)`. So why are you calling `mysql_affected_rows` in the first place?

Comment: @Jon : this is happening because `a) the fields were unchanged`. Even the fields are not changed, how should I say that edit is done? Also when I do echo $sql, I get response as 1 (always), so I believe false will not be right way to compare...

Comment: @FahimParkar: If you had asked "how can I detect that the user has not changed the input fields so I can display an error" we would have gotten here much sooner. And of course the answer is: fetch them from the database and compare them with the values you want to use for the update.

Comment: @Jon : What I was trying to do is when updated_rows==1 (because at one time I can only 1 person data in text field), I will say user data is updated

Comment: @Jon : That I understand. But usually I have seen that after clicking edit, if I don't even change data and click save, i get response as data is saved...

Comment: @FahimParkar - you say "I am using PDO but..". Not sure what you're saying here; the PDO code to do what you're showing wouldn't be any more complex than the `mysql_query()` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [mysqli_info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php), just after executing the query

```
$string = mysqli_info ( $link );
```

returns a string having the relevant information, like for UPDATE

```
Rows matched: 40 Changed: 40 Warnings: 0
```

in your case, one row updated but no change, you should get

```
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0
```

You can retrieve the value from

```
preg_match("/Rows matched: (\d+)/", $string, $matches);
$number_of_rows = intval($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's right mysql behavior of [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).
But you can use some wiered trick if you really want this.

```
$sql = mysqli_query("UPDATE userInfo SET id=@id:=id
                    fullName='$fullName',
                    mobileNumber='$mobileNumber'
                    WHERE id=$tagNumberId");
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'select @id');
if (array(null)!==mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

P.S. You MUST use prepared statements for yours applications.

P.P.S. with this method you can't recognize count, but there is no need if you use update on id.